# Swift: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I access class property

Tags: swift2

EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs when I access (read or rewrite) property of class instance.

```
class MyUIImageView:UIImageView {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
    var hand: String = ""
}
@IBOutlet weak var myInstance: MyUIImageView!
func rewrite() {
    ...
    myInstance.hand = "..."  // Error!
}
func read() {
    ...
    var tmp: String = myInstance.hand  // Error!
}
```

Do you know how to fix this error?

#### ・2016/1/31

`Unknown class MyUIImageView in Interface Builder` was found in log, and Module field of Custom Class is "None".

Comment: Is myInstance correctly connected in the interface builder?

Comment: Yes, I checked on connection inspector.

Comment: Try to change the var name from description to another name. Because there is a function description which is used for the debug output. Maybe thats the error

Comment: Sorry, property real name is not "description" but "hand". I write "description" here for easiness. The names of others (property, function or class) are real.

Answer (score 1):

either `myInstance` isn't set or `myInstance` isn't a `MyUIImageView`